# Установить соотвествие между цифрой и словом

Tags: xml, asp.net, html

Добрый день! Помогите решить проблему. Есть некий отчет, который из базы данных тянет инфу. В последний столбец попадают цифры (50, 40, 60 и т.д). Задача состоит в следующем: заменить эти цифры на человеческие слова ("ПОЛУЧЕН", "ОТПРАВЛЕН" и т.д.). Как установить соотвествие между цифрой и словом? Интересует последний столбец "СТАТУС"

Сам отчет прикладываю

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<meta name="description" content="Статистика по переводам">
<title>Статистика по переводам</title>
<style type="text/css">
 body {font-size: 9pt; font-weight: normal}
 table {font-size: 9pt; font-weight: normal}
 table.brdr {border-left: none; border-top: none; border-right: 1px solid gray; border-bottom: 1px solid gray}
 table.brdr td {border-left: 1px solid gray; border-top: 1px solid gray; border-right: none; border-bottom: none}
 h1 {font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold}
 h2 {font-size: 12pt; font-weight: normal}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align=center>Сведения об отправленных переводах в период с <%= Report.InitialDate.DisplayText %> по <%=

Report.FinalDate.DisplayText %></h1>
<%
Currency.Locate('Currency_ID',Report.Currency.Value);
var defcurr=Currency.Currency_SName.DisplayText;
%>
<h2>Валюта: <%= Currency.Currency_Name.DisplayText %></h2>
<table class=brdr cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td align=center>Дата</td>
<td align=center>Номер</td>
<td align=center>Сумма перевода</td>
<td align=center>Собственная<br>комиссия</td>
<td align=center>Комиссия банка<br>получателя / РЦ</td>
<td align=center>Суммарная коммисия</td>
<td align=center>Пукт отправки</td>
<td align=center>ФИО отправителя</td>
<td align=center>ФИО получателя</td>
<td align=center>Статус перевода</td>
</tr>
<%
var SumAmount=0.0, SumCommis1=0.0, SumCommis2=0.0, SumCommisSum=0.0;
var amount, commis1, commis2;
var e=new Enumerator(Transfer.Records);
for (; !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()) {
  amount=Transfer.Amount.Value;
  SumAmount+=amount;
  commis1=Transfer.Commis1.Value;
  SumCommis1+=commis1;
  commis2=Transfer.Commis2.Value+Transfer.Commis3.Value;
  SumCommis2+=commis2;
  SumCommis=Transfer.CommisSum.Value;
  SumCommisSum+=SumCommis;
%>
<tr>
<td align=center>&nbsp;<%= Transfer.Transfer_Date.DisplayText %>&nbsp;</td>
<td align=center>&nbsp;<%= Transfer.Alter_Control.DisplayText %>&nbsp;</td>
<td align=right>&nbsp;<%= amount %>&nbsp;<%= defcurr %>&nbsp;</td>
<td align=right>&nbsp;<%= commis1 %>&nbsp;<%= defcurr %>&nbsp;</td>
<td align=right>&nbsp;<%= commis2 %>&nbsp;<%= defcurr %>&nbsp;</td>
<td align=center>&nbsp;<%= Transfer.CommisSum.DisplayText %>&nbsp;<%= defcurr %>&nbsp;</td>  
<td align=right>&nbsp;<%= Transfer.Sender_BankID.DisplayText %>&nbsp;</td>
<td align=right>&nbsp;<%= Transfer.Sender_LastName.DisplayText %>&nbsp;<%= Transfer.Sender_FirstName.DisplayText

%>&nbsp;<%= Transfer.Sender_MiddleName.DisplayText %>&nbsp;</td>
<td align=right>&nbsp;<%= Transfer.Receiver_LastName.DisplayText %>&nbsp;<%= Transfer.Receiver_FirstName.DisplayText

%>&nbsp;<%= Transfer.Receiver_MiddleName.DisplayText %>&nbsp;</td>
<td align=center>&nbsp;<%= Transfer.Transfer_Status.DisplayText %>&nbsp;</td>

</tr>
<% } %>
<tr>
<td align=left style="font-weight: bold">&nbsp;Итого:</td>
<td align=right style="font-weight: bold">&nbsp;</td>
<td align=right style="font-weight: bold">&nbsp;<%= SumAmount %>&nbsp;<%= defcurr %>&nbsp;</td>
<td align=right style="font-weight: bold">&nbsp;<%= SumCommis1 %>&nbsp;<%= defcurr %>&nbsp;</td>
<td align=right style="font-weight: bold">&nbsp;<%= SumCommis2 %>&nbsp;<%= defcurr %>&nbsp;</td>
<td align=right style="font-weight: bold">&nbsp;<%= SumCommisSum %>&nbsp;<%= defcurr %>&nbsp;</td>
<td align=right style="font-weight: bold">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td align=right style="font-weight: bold">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td align=right style="font-weight: bold">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td align=right style="font-weight: bold">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте проверку какое число и в зависимости от этого выведете слово, примерно так:

```
<td> <% var status_word = "";
switch (Transfer.Transfer_Status.DisplayText)
{
case 50:
status_word = "ПОЛУЧЕН";
break;

case 40:
status_word = "ОТПРАВЛЕН";
break;

/* и так далее */

}
Response.Write(txt);
%></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Заведите словарь и по словарю сопоствляйте. Примерно так

code-behind

```
Dictionary<int, string> Map = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {50, "Получен"}, {40, "Отправлен"}
};
```

view

```
<td> <%= Map[Transfer.Transfer_Status.DisplayText] %></td>
```